# using @User.IsInRole("Admin") in MVC VIEW

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I using @User.IsInRole("Admin")   in mvc4 
 when i use this command in global.asax it return true  but when I use in view of mvc it return sql server connection error .

Comment: You probably _don't_ want to do that in global.asax, because according to what you're doing there, _all_ your users will be marked as admin (global.asax is for _application_-level events). Anyway **what is the exact error**?

Answer (score 0):

protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Context.User == null)
                return;

```
        var userService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUserService>();

        UserStatus userStatus = userService.GetStatus(Context.User.Identity.Name);

        if (userStatus.IsBaned)
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie == null || authCookie.Value == "")
            return;

        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);


        // retrieve roles from UserData
        if (authTicket == null) return;
        string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(',');

        if (userStatus.Role != roles[0])
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(Context.User.Identity, roles);

    }
```